# A list of ticker to get setor and name

Tags: python, yfinance

```
   import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
```

filename=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\from_python\data_from_python.xlsx'

```
yeah = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='entry')
stock = []

stock = list(yeah['name'])
stock = [ s.replace('\xa0', '') for s in stock if not pd.isna(s) ]


adj_close=pd.DataFrame([])
high_price=pd.DataFrame([])
low_price=pd.DataFrame([])
volume=pd.DataFrame([])

print(stock)


['^GSPC', 'NQ=F', 'AAU', 'ALB', 'AOS', 'APPS', 'AQB', 'ASPN', 'ATHM', 'AZRE', 'BCYC', 'BGNE', 'CAT', 'CC', 'CLAR', 'CLCT', 'CMBM', 'CMT', 'CRDF', 'CYD', 'DE', 'DKNG', 'EARN', 'EMN', 'FBIO', 'FBRX', 'FCX', 'FLXS', 'FMC', 'FMCI', 'GME', 'GRVY', 'HAIN', 'HBM', 'HIBB', 'IEX', 'IOR', 'KFS', 'MAXR', 'MPX', 'MRTX', 'NSTG', 'NVCR', 'NVO', 'OESX', 'PENN', 'PLL', 'PRTK', 'RDY', 'REGI', 'REKR', 'SBE', 'SQM', 'TCON', 'TCS', 'TGB', 'TPTX', 'TRIL', 'UEC', 'VCEL', 'VOXX', 'WIT', 'WKHS', 'XNCR']

for symbol in stock:
    adj_close[symbol] = web.get_data_yahoo([symbol],start,end)['Adj Close']
```

I have a list of tickers, I have got the adj close price, how can get these tickers NAME and SECTORS?

for single ticker I found in web, it can be done like as below

```
sbux = yf.Ticker("SBUX")
tlry = yf.Ticker("TLRY")

print(sbux.info['sector'])
print(tlry.info['sector'])
```

How can I make it as a `dataframe` that I can put the data into excel as I am doing for `adj` price.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this answer using a package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  Disclaimer:  I am the author of the package.

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import pandas as pd

symbols = ['^GSPC', 'NQ=F', 'AAU', 'ALB', 'AOS', 'APPS', 'AQB', 'ASPN', 'ATHM', 'AZRE', 'BCYC', 'BGNE', 'CAT', 'CC', 'CLAR', 'CLCT', 'CMBM', 'CMT', 'CRDF', 'CYD', 'DE', 'DKNG', 'EARN', 'EMN', 'FBIO', 'FBRX', 'FCX', 'FLXS', 'FMC', 'FMCI', 'GME', 'GRVY', 'HAIN', 'HBM', 'HIBB', 'IEX', 'IOR', 'KFS', 'MAXR', 'MPX', 'MRTX', 'NSTG', 'NVCR', 'NVO', 'OESX', 'PENN', 'PLL', 'PRTK', 'RDY', 'REGI', 'REKR', 'SBE', 'SQM', 'TCON', 'TCS', 'TGB', 'TPTX', 'TRIL', 'UEC', 'VCEL', 'VOXX', 'WIT', 'WKHS', 'XNCR']

# Create Ticker instance, passing symbols as first argument
# Optional asynchronous argument allows for asynchronous requests
tickers = Ticker(symbols, asynchronous=True)

data = tickers.get_modules("summaryProfile quoteType")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).T

# flatten dicts within each column, creating new dataframes
dataframes = [pd.json_normalize([x for x in df[module] if isinstance(x, dict)]) for module in ['summaryProfile', 'quoteType']]

# concat dataframes from previous step
df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)

# View columns
df.columns
Index(['address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'country', 'phone',
       'fax', 'website', 'industry', 'sector', 'longBusinessSummary',
       'fullTimeEmployees', 'companyOfficers', 'maxAge', 'exchange',
       'quoteType', 'symbol', 'underlyingSymbol', 'shortName', 'longName',
       'firstTradeDateEpochUtc', 'timeZoneFullName', 'timeZoneShortName',
       'uuid', 'messageBoardId', 'gmtOffSetMilliseconds', 'maxAge'],
      dtype='object')

# Data you're looking for
df[['symbol', 'shortName', 'sector']].head(10)
      symbol                      shortName                  sector
0  NQZ20.CME              Nasdaq 100 Dec 20                     NaN
1        ALB          Albemarle Corporation         Basic Materials
2        AOS         A.O. Smith Corporation             Industrials
3       ASPN           Aspen Aerogels, Inc.             Industrials
4        AAU         Almaden Minerals, Ltd.         Basic Materials
5      ^GSPC                        S&P 500                     NaN
6       ATHM                  Autohome Inc.  Communication Services
7        AQB  AquaBounty Technologies, Inc.      Consumer Defensive
8       APPS          Digital Turbine, Inc.              Technology
9       BCYC       Bicycle Therapeutics plc              Healthcare
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i couldn't download the yahooquery. I use Anaconda, and install the terminal windowns\system32\cmd.exe.............The error: could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Access is denied:.........consider using the  user option or check the perimissions. ........Sorry that I am an idiot in programming ..how to do ?

Comment: The package isn't currently available through conda, you'll have to install it with pip - `pip install yahooquery`

Comment: Very good performance. I just tried with 10 stocks and it came back pretty quick. I used the modules `get_modules("summaryProfile summaryDetail")` so I got no symbol in the resulting dataset. Is there a simple way of including it, without having to request the quoteType module?

Answer (score 0):

It processes stocks and sectors at the same time. However, some stocks do not have a sector, so an error countermeasure is added.
Since the issue column name consists of sector and issue name, we change it to a hierarchical column and update the retrieved data frame. Finally, I save it in CSV format to import it into Excel. I've only tried some of the stocks due to the large number of stocks, so there may be some issues.

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader.data as web

yf.pdr_override()

start = "2018-01-01"
end = "2019-01-01"

# symbol = ['^GSPC', 'NQ=F', 'AAU', 'ALB', 'AOS', 'APPS', 'AQB', 'ASPN', 'ATHM', 'AZRE', 'BCYC', 'BGNE', 'CAT', 
#'CC', 'CLAR', 'CLCT', 'CMBM', 'CMT', 'CRDF', 'CYD', 'DE', 'DKNG', 'EARN', 'EMN', 'FBIO', 'FBRX', 'FCX', 'FLXS', 
#'FMC', 'FMCI', 'GME', 'GRVY', 'HAIN', 'HBM', 'HIBB', 'IEX', 'IOR', 'KFS', 'MAXR', 'MPX', 'MRTX', 'NSTG', 'NVCR',
#'NVO', 'OESX', 'PENN', 'PLL', 'PRTK', 'RDY', 'REGI', 'REKR', 'SBE', 'SQM', 'TCON', 'TCS', 'TGB', 'TPTX', 'TRIL', 
#'UEC', 'VCEL', 'VOXX', 'WIT', 'WKHS', 'XNCR']
stock = ['^GSPC', 'NQ=F', 'AAU', 'ALB', 'AOS', 'APPS']

adj_close = pd.DataFrame([])

for symbol in stock:
    try:
        sector = yf.Ticker(symbol).info['sector']
        name = yf.Ticker(symbol).info['shortName']
    except:
        sector = 'None'
        name = 'None'
    adj_close[sector, symbol] = web.get_data_yahoo(symbol, start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(adj_close.columns)
adj_close.columns = idx
adj_close.head()

                    None    Basic Materials Industrials Technology
            ^GSPC_None  NQ=F_None   AAU_None    ALB_Albemarle Corporation   AOS_A.O. Smith Corporation  APPS_Digital Turbine, Inc.
2018-01-02  2695.810059 6514.75 1.03    125.321663  58.657742   1.79
2018-01-03  2713.060059 6584.50 1.00    125.569397  59.010468   1.87
2018-01-04  2723.989990 6603.50 0.98    124.073502  59.286930   1.86
2018-01-05  2743.149902 6667.75 1.00    125.502716  60.049587   1.96
2018-01-08  2747.709961 6688.00 0.95    130.962250  60.335583   1.96


# for excel 
adj_close.to_csv('stock.csv', sep=',')
```

Comment: Thanks,  it works, but how about the NAME for the companies.

Comment: I added the name of the company in the same way. The code has been updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  sort_adj_close.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='adj close')
sort_high_price.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='high price')
sort_low_price.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='low price')
sort_volume.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='volume')   , I want to separate Name and sector from adj  close price into another excel sheet, can I do that ?

Comment: I am now separating vol, adj price, high price and low price into different excel sheets...I want to have another separated sheet for information like Name, Sector, earning etc. thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't have experience with writing directly to excel, but I wonder if it's possible with the technique you're commenting on. As it has evolved from the first issue, I think it would be quicker and more likely to get answers from more people if it were a separate question.

Comment: ok , I may use your above suggestion first. it is very useful already, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
pd.options.display.max_rows = 2000


# Define the list of stock symbols
master_list = pd.read_csv('master_list.csv')
master_list = master_list['yfin_ticker'].values.tolist()

# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name","Ticker", "Industry", "Sector"])

# Loop through the stocks list and retrieve industry and sector information
for i in master_list:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(i)
    stock_info = ticker.info
    name = stock_info.get('shortName', 'N/A')
    industry = stock_info.get('industry', 'N/A')
    sector = stock_info.get('sector', 'N/A')
    biz = stock_info.get('longBusinessSummary', 'N/A')
    data = {"Name": name, "Ticker": i, "Industry": industry, "Sector": sector, "Business":biz}
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])], ignore_index=True)

df.sort_values(by=['Sector'], ascending=True)

    Name    Ticker  Industry    Sector
105 SKSHU PAINT CO LTD  603737.SS   Specialty Chemicals Basic Materials
23  CMOC                3993.HK Other Industrial Metals & Mining    Basic Materials
68  CHINA JUSHI CO LTD  600176.SS   Building Materials  Basic Materials
```

Using the ticker.info, you can scale up and down depending on your needs. Still have to use for loops which is tremendously slow for a large list of ticker